# what is the appropriate formula for finding number of words taken 3 at a time?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

lets say i have $$ADIIN$$
Now the find number of words formed taken 3 at a time, where two are alike and one is different
here i mapped all the possible permuations manually
$$ IIA, IID, IIN
$$
$$ IAI, IDI, INI
$$
$$ AII, DII, NII
$$
now when i use the formula  $_5P_3= 20\times3$ that's not even close to real answer
so what's the appropriate formula for these type of problems I'm really confused

Comment: Account for repetitions—there are two Is here.

Comment: you mean $\frac{_5P_3}{2!}$? that still doesnt give the answer

Comment: Is there some implicit restriction here that the word *must* contain two $I$’s? Otherwise, there are more words than the ones you’ve listed.

Comment: Add the number of words with a repeated letter to the number of words that do not contain a repeated letter.

Comment: sorry my bad i forgot to mention I'll edit, yes "I" needs to be there

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing many options:

```
ADI  AID  DAI  DIA  IAD  IDA
ADN  AND  DAN  DNA  NAD  NDA
ANI  AIN  NAI  NIA  IAN  INA
DNI  DIN  NDI  NID  IND  IDN
```

Now the problem with using $^5P_2$ is that it assumes all your five letters are different - it counts all triples from say ADIJN. What this means in practice is that it counts any triple with at least one I twice - it counts `ADI` as both `ADI` and `ADJ`, and it counts `AII` as `AIJ` and `AJI`.

Of the combinations from ADIJN, there are $^3P_3$ which don't use I or J. There are $^5P_3$ in total, so there are $^5P_3-{}^3P_3$ which do include I or J. These ones only correspond to half as many options from ADIIN.

Therefore the overall number of possibilities is $$^3P_3+\frac{{}^5P_3-{}^3P_3}{2}=\frac{{}^5P_3+{}^3P_3}{2}=33.$$
In general this argument works where you have $n$ letters with exactly one pair and want to count the number of strings of length $r$, the answer is $\frac{{}^nP_r+{}^{n-2}P_r}{2}$.

Comment: im sorry but there is an restriction that two should be alike and one should be different, i forgot to mention

Comment: @Rambalheartremo in that case it's a much simpler problem. You have to take two Is and another letter. There are three options for the other letter, and three for which position you put it in, so the answer is $3\times 3=9$.

Comment: $^nP_r$ is about counting the number *without* restrictions, so it's not going to be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

We are making a 3 letter word from the letters A,D,I,I,N

When you take two Is : No. Of ways of selection of 3 letter word= $^3C_1$ . Total possible arrangements = $^3C_1 × \frac{3!}{2!}=9$

When you take zero or one I : No. Of ways of selection of 3 letter word= $^4C_3$ . Total possible arrangements = $^4C_3 × 3!=24$

Total possible ways $= 9+24=33$

$\mathbf{Edit:}$
After reading your comment, first case (with two Is ) is what you are looking for. So there are 9 possible ways.

Tip: First find the number of possible selections and then no. of arrangements for these type of questions.

$^5P_3=^5C_3 × 3!$ .Out of $^5C_3$ combinations $AI_1D$ and $AI_2D$ are taken as two different combinations but $I_1$ and $I_2$ are ought to be same. This results in double counting of all combinations with one $I$ i.e. 3 extra combinations. Thus there are only $^5C_3-3=7$ possible combinations. And not all of them have $3!$ possible arrangements. Whenever there are two Is in the selection, its arrangement can be done in only 3 ways and not $3!=6$ ways, so simple permutation $^5P_3$ is not what you need here. The answer written by another user explains this clearly.